# Is there a nice way to convert the built-in JPEG compressed image message to an AWT BufferedImage?

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, rosjava, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like it says on the tin, we need to process a compressed_image transport from Java code. We aren't developing on Android and so can't leverage any of the Android-specific stuff packaged in to rosjava.

Specifically, we need to go from a CompressedImage message to a native AWT BufferedImage.  But to do this, we need a lot of information required to decompress the image that we can't seem to get a hold of (things like width and height, which I suppose we could get from the CameraInfo but we're trying to keep the number of subscription handlers to a minimum because they seem to be pretty heavyweight in all of our benchmarks).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60086/is-there-a-nice-way-to-convert-the-built-in-jpeg-compressed-image-message-to-an-awt-bufferedimage?/) by [dljsjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4417/dljsjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like this was as simple as using a `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ImageIO.read()`.  We ran in to some hiccups because we forgot to offset from the `ChannelBuffer` but we got it figured out.

---

Originally posted by [dljsjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4417/dljsjr/) with karma: 51 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2014-12-15**:
Hey, working on the same problem, what do you mean by offset the ChannelBuffer?

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-04-11**:
I'm having the same problem also, could you post more details about your solution?